# React Project working but not displaying some components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

i am trying to build a portfolio website using react and i am using react-router-dom for navigation.

everything was working for a while then i made a stupid mistake of keeping the project in onedrive and had some trouble.

link to code: https://github.com/Raghav-rv28/portfolio-website

Live: https://raghav-rv28.github.io/portfolio-website/, this is not really helpful as we cannot see anything but you can see the screenshots below,

when i run the project on my local machine it runs :

[image][image]as you can see the elements are there but they just don't appear to me for some reason.

Some of the Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './Components/Layout'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import About from './Components/About'
import Contact from './Components/Contact'
import Interests from './Components/Interests'
import Projects from './Components/Projects'
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
          <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element = { <Layout />} >
            <Route index element={< Home/>} />
            <Route path='About' element={< About/>} />
            <Route path='Contact' element={< Contact/>} />
            <Route path='Interests' element={< Interests/>} />
            <Route path='Projects' element={< Projects/>} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Layout.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.scss';
import SideNavbar from '../SideNavbar/index';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';



export default function Layout(){
    return(
    <div className="App">
     <SideNavbar /> 
        <div className="page">
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    </div>)
}
```

index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my stupid As* forgot to import the animation library i'm using and the opacity for the pages was set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You nested your routes for (Home, About, Contact, etc.) inside the "Layout" route. This means that react router will render BOTH "Layout" and whichever component is provided by a matching nested route.

Try restructuring your routes like this:

```
<>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element = { <Layout />} />
        <Route index element={< Home/>} />
        <Route path='About' element={< About/>} />
        <Route path='Contact' element={< Contact/>} />
        <Route path='Interests' element={< Interests/>} />
        <Route path='Projects' element={< Projects/>} />
    </Routes>
</>
```

Comment: when i do this, i don't get anything, the way i did (nested) at-least shows the sidenavbar, keeping the routes separate results in even navbar not rendering. i think the issue is with Route but i just cant figure out what.

Comment: my Layout file has the sidenavbar and the <Outlet /> from 'react-route-dom', which renders the pages